# Pacote corrplot

Tags: r

Como posso adicionar a significância as correlação sem que ocorra sobreposição entre o símbolo (*) e o valor da correlação??

De modo que fique como na imagem  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Forneça o código que você utilizou e os seus dados (comando `dput`) para que a gente possa reproduzir o seu problema e te ajudar da melhor forma

Answer (score 3):

Para isso, eu utilizo o pacote `PerformanceAnalytics`. Veja:

```
PerformanceAnalytics::chart.Correlation(iris[, -5])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Via `corrplot` não é possível/teria que fazer muita programação. [Nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012529/correlation-corrplot-), eles apresentam uma opção via `corrgram` mas não é prática na minha opinião. Se fosse para usar o `corrplot` eu usaria algo assim:

```
m.cor <- cor(iris[, -5])
m.sig <- cor.mtest(iris[, -5])$p
corrplot(corr = m.cor, outline = F, p.mat = m.sig, tl.srt = 0, 
     addCoef.col = "black", method = "square", type = "upper", diag = F, insig = "pch")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em que o "X" representa que o coeficiente não foi diferente de zero (não foi significativo).