# Gráfico de correlação com coeficientes e significância juntos

Tags: r

Estou tentando representar uma matriz de correlação que contenha os coeficientes de correlação e a significância no mesmo gráfico.Já li em outro post que com o corrplot não seria possível colocar estas duas informações na mesma célula do gráfico.
Seria possível colocar na parte superior os coeficientes de correlação e na metade inferior as significâncias?

[image: Correlação]

```
library(readxl)
seed <- read_excel("seed.xlsx")
seed
cor(seed, method = "pearson")
M <- cor(seed, method = "pearson")
library(corrplot)
library(RColorBrewer)
corrplot(M, type = "upper", method = "color", order = "original", outline = "white", 
         tl.col="black", tl.srt=45, addCoef.col = "black",
         col = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow", "red"))(20))
library(Hmisc)
m <- rcorr(as.matrix(seed))
m
P <- cor.mtest(seed, conf.level = .95)
corrplot(M, p.mat = P$p, insig = "label_sig", sig.level = c(.001, .01, .05),
         pch.cex = 2, pch.col = "white", type = "upper", method = "color", 
         order = "original", outline = "white", tl.col="black", tl.srt=45,diag = FALSE,
         addCoef.col = "black", col = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow", "red"))(20)
```

Comment: Por favor anexo o arquivo seed.xlsx ou melhor ainda, forneça os dados através de dput(head(seed, 20)). Fiz uma pesquisa, e não encontrei nenhum pacote pronto que forneça ambas informações do jeito que você sugere. Pq vc quer apresentar de forma literal ambos valores? Não acha que o valor de correlação é mais importante que o valor-p nesse caso (assumindo que todas as variáveis tem n igual)

Comment: > dput(head(seed, 20))
structure(list(TT = c(151.65, 169.51, 173.91, 158.95, 159.05,146.85, 157.21, 146.01, 178.45, 165.75, 185.95, 143.81, 182.25, 175.51, 217.95, 273.75, 217.61, 206.01, 213.75), RT = c(145.33, 120.15, 135.31, 148.12, 127.45, 112.05, 130.21, 113.65, 136.71, 
126.65, 153.61, 113.55, 148.21, 166.85, 188.45, 234.75, 195.31, 199.32, 193.11), NRI = c(4.91, 4.51, 5.41, 5.35, 6.15, 6.61, 4.51, 5.95, 5.55, 4.51, 5.11, 5.51, 5.95, 6.91, 7.11, 6.55, 8.21, 6.75, 8.11), continua

Comment: NSI = c(182.51, 95.45, 124.21, 199.91, 117.41, 166.35, 189.65, 171.75, 203.35, 166.25, 125.45, 128.91, 143.51, 187.41, 211.81, 169.01, 216.61, 77.85, 262.41), WTS = c(3.46, 3.38, 4.07, 3.89, 3.33, 3.78, 2.88, 3.34, 3.02, 3.68, 3.55, 4.17, 3.66, 3.11, 3.09, 3.41, 3.29, 3.18, 2.91), SY = c(79.81, 19.97, 60.92, 92.74, 23.92, 55.43, 57.44, 53.29, 56.62, 58.08, 53.83, 59.55, 55.26, 75.13, 73.18, 90.69, 78.48, 107.89, 81.46)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: 6 variáveis quantitativas com 19 repetições. Obrigado!

Comment: esse resultado fica melhor se colocado no corpo da pergunta, de qualquer forma, nao encontrei a resposta especifica para a sua pergunta

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme! Te agradeço a atenção. Ainda que eu seja um principiante do R, migrando do SAS, para aproveitar as parte gráfica do R, na lógica seria possível dividir o gráfico.... Vou dar um tempo e retomar essa empreitada. O meu muito obrigado, abraço.

Answer (score 2):

eu fiz uma pesquisa similar dessa já algum tempo, e refiz novamente, mas não consegui encontrar tal resultado. Sendo assim, eu pensei que não seria uma visualização interessante, pois ninguém fez antes e é algo simples.

Dessa forma, eu sugiro tu usar isso algo [assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/335150/pacote-corrplot/338736#338736).

Mas você também consegue programar o que tu deseja. Basta, utilizar um `for` para as variáveis das colunas, e outro para as linhas e armazenar o resultado da função `cor.test` em um objeto (ex.: `corre`). No mesmo laço, na parte triangular superior da matriz você coloca o resultado de `corre$estimate` (correlação), e na triangular inferior o resultado de `corre$p.value`. Em seguida, tu pode printar o resultado dessa `matriz`/`data.frame` combinando as funções `kable` e [`kableExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) (para montar o layout como você deseja).